# Azure Application Gateway - Multiple site hosting with a single BE pool

Tags: azure-application-gateway

0

In our BE we have 2 services running on the same BE VM, they have to run together cause they share the same DB. i would like to use AAG with multiple sites topology configured with a single BE pool. the idea is that the affinity cookie will make sure that every requests in the same session will land on the same BE VM even if they were made for a different site (sub domain).

will it work as intended?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can utilize azure application affinity cookie it used to send the primary request ask to Application directed to the same backend server until users' activity goes off. Application gateway can direct subsequent traffic from a user session to the same server

*Make sure you can add backend listeners, routing rules, HTTP settings and health probes.*

For more information in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Azure Application Gateway - Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/quick-create-portal)

[multiple site hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/multiple-site-overview)